# 2x2 grid in Flexbox with fixed width column

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Is it possible to create this grid with Flexbox:

```
----------
A1 | B1
----------
A2 | B2
----------
```

A1&A2 have a fixed width (50px) and B1&B2 fill the remaining space. I don't want to create wrappers for the columns, because I would like to reorder the cells on mobile.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Simple 2X2 Flexbox grid — fixed and fluid

**Compatibility**: [IE 11 + and all modern browsers.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) Safari is supported with the `-webkit-` prefix.

The stars of this show are:

- The `display: flex` and `flex-wrap: wrap` properties for the container. The "wrap" value allows the contents of the container to break onto a new line as required.
- The [`flex` shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) property:

  > [The initial value of the flex property is] the concatenation of the initial values of its longhand
  >   properties:
  >
  > - flex-grow: 0
  > - flex-shrink: 1
  > - flex-basis: auto

  [This is an easy guide to Flexbox over on CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

In our example we use:

- `display: flex` and `flex-wrap: wrap` on the container div
- `flex: 1 1 calc(100% - 50px)` for the two re-sizeable divs. This tells the div to have a default width of 100% minus the 50px of the fixed cell. Technically it is allowed to grow and shrink, though as it is set as a percentage, it would re-size regardless.
- `flex: 0 0 50px` for the fixed cells. This tells the div to have a default width of 50px and then not grow or shrink.

### Complete Example

```css
.flex-grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 500px;
}
.grid-item {
  flex: 1 1 calc(100% - 50px);
  background: #F90;
  border-top: solid 1px #000;
}
.grid-item:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #F00;
  flex: 0 0 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-grid">
  <div class="grid-item">
    A1
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    B1
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    A2
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item">
    B2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I had an issue with this approach in IE11. Specifically the flex-basis calc in the .grid-item rule does not seem to work. I had to change it from calc to auto which seemed to solve my issue.

Answer (score 4):

Use width: `calc(100% - 50px)` for the width of B1 and B2

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/h7c514q4/)**

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 40%;
  height: 100px;
  max-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.container div:nth-child(-n + 2) {
  background: yellow;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.container div:nth-child(n + 3) {
  background: aqua;
  height: 50px;
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>A1</div>
  <div>A2</div>
  <div>B1 - Where B1&B2 fill the remaining space</div>
  <div>B2 - Where B1&B2 fill the remaining space</div>
</div>
```